# (TypeError: 'float' object is not callable) when doing math

Tags: python, callable

I am writing a code to calculate all of the energy levels for an electron as it jumps to different orbital levels in the Bohr model. I have some math written, but when I try to run it it says TypeError: 'float' object is not callable. What do I need to do?

Here is my code:

```
loopone = True
if (work == Element_symbols[0]):
energy = ((charge[0]*(0-13.6))/1)
print ('This is the energy level for the electron at the N=1 state.')
print (energy)
print ('These are all of the possible energies from the n=6 level')
nrgone = (-13.6((1/(5*5)-(1/(6*6)))))
nrgtwo = (-13.6((1/(4*4)-(1/(6*6)))))
nrgthree = (-13.6((1/(3*3)-(1/(6*6)))))
nrgfour = (-13.6((1/(2*2)-(1/(6*6)))))
nrgfive = (-13.6((1/(1*1)-(1/(6*6)))))
Energies = (nrgone, nrgtwo, nrgthree, nrgfour, nrgfive)
print (Energies)
loopone = False
```

Comment: You're missing an operator (probably `*`) in each `nrgone = (-13.6((1/(5*5)-(1/(6*6)))))` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem is here

```
nrgone = (-13.6((1/(5*5)-(1/(6*6)))))
```

Don't you mean (notice the multiplication sign)?

```
nrgone = (-13.6*((1/(5*5)-(1/(6*6)))))
```

Comment: That was it, thank you. I just missed it.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark next to it